# Relations with "for each" composition and its properties (coming from profunctors with end composition)

Tags: ct.category-theory, 2-categories, profunctors

$\newcommand{\sq}{\mathbin{\square}}$The usual composition $S\diamond R$ of two relations $R\colon A⇸B$ and $S\colon B⇸C$ is defined as follows:

- For each $(a,c)\in A\times C$, we declare $a\sim_{S\diamond R}c$ if **there exists**  $b\in B$ such that $a\sim_{R}b$ and $b\sim_{S}c$.

Now, consider the relation $S\sq R$ defined as follows:

- For each $(a,c)\in A\times C$, we declare $a\sim_{S\sq R}c$ if **for each** $b\in B$, we have $a\sim_{R}b$ and $b\sim_{S}c$.

Intuitively, the composition $\sq$ is quite weird, although its categorical origin is at least natural: categorically, $\diamond$ is a 0-categorical analogue of the coend composition of profunctors, where we view relations as morphisms $R\colon A\times B\to\{\mathtt{true},\mathtt{false}\}$ and then have
$$(S\diamond R)^{a}_{c}=\int^{b\in B}R^{a}_{b}\times S^{b}_{c},$$
whereas we have
$$(S\sq R)^{a}_{c}=\int_{b\in B}R^{a}_{b}\times S^{b}_{c},$$
where:

- The product $\times$ on $\{\mathtt{true},\mathtt{false}\}:=\{\mathtt{t},\mathtt{f}\}$ is given by logical conjunction;
- The coend $\int^{b\in B}$ is given by $\vee_{b\in B}$, the join in the poset $\{\mathtt{t},\mathtt{f}\}$ equipped with logical implication $\implies$.
- The end $\int_{b\in B}$ is given by $\wedge_{b\in B}$, the meet in $(\{\mathtt{t},\mathtt{f}\},\mathord{\implies})$.

---

1. Has $\sq$ found any natural use in practice?
2. What kinds of nice properties does the 2-category $\mathsf{Rel}^{\sq}$ given by sets, relations and inclusions with the composition $\sq$ has?

For instance, while $\mathsf{Rel}^{\diamond}$ has right Kan lifts and right Kan extensions, $\mathsf{Rel}^{\sq}$ has left ones. Other properties would include whether $\mathsf{Rel}^{\sq}$ is co/complete (1- or 2-categorically), what the adjunctions in $\mathsf{Rel}^{\sq}$ are, etc.

3. Are there any references which study $\sq$ or $\mathsf{Rel}^{\sq}$?
4. (This is slightly outside of the scope of the question, but I'm also interested in profunctors with end composition (and the properties $\mathsf{Prof}$ enjoys with such a composition). I'm sure these have been considered before, and likely the results for those are adaptable to $\mathsf{Rel}^{\sq}$)

Comment: If you had $\forall b.a\sim b\lor b\sim c$, this would be the composition for **apartness**.  Do you really mean $\land$? (Or the categorical analogues with $\Pi$ and $+$ instead of $\times$.)

Comment: Yes, I do mean those as in the question, though I know realise I also want to figure out all of the questions I outlined above for apartness and for the composition $\exists b. a\sim b\vee b\sim c$. Thank you so much for the suggestion!

Comment: @PaulTaylor On a related note, do you know if there is an established symbol in common usage for the apartness composition of two relations $R$ and $S$, like writing $R\text{(symbol)}S$ for the relation where $a\sim_{R\text{(symbol)}S}c$ iff $\forall b.a\sim b\vee b\sim c$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operation $\square$ defined with $\forall$ and $\land$ is associative, because both $a(R\square(S\square T))d$ and $a((R\square S)\square T)d$ expand to
$$ (\forall b_1.\ a R b_1)\land(\forall b_2 c_1.\ b_2 S c_1)\land(\forall c_2.\ c_2 T d). $$
However, it does not define a category unless you restrict to relations between singletons. This is because the unit laws give
$$ \forall a_1 a_2 b_1 b_2.\quad
a_2 R b_1 \iff a_1 R b_1 \iff a_1 R b_2 $$
for any relation $R$.

A "category" without identities can be turned into a genuine category by taking its idempotents as objects (Karoubi construction), but in this case the idempotents are "constant" relations in the above sense, so there is no improvement.

The only useful ways of forming this composition use $\exists$ with $\land$ or $\forall$ with $\lor$.

I'll leave it to you to adapt this to type-theoretic products and sums or to (co)ends, together with  (co)products.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, Paul! I really should have checked whether the $\square$ composition was unital+associative, it's disappointing it fails to be so =/

Comment: I think I'll try figuring out which of the 16 magma structures on $\{\mathtt{t},\mathtt{f}\}$ with $\forall$ and $\exists$ give associative and unital compositions for relations one by one next, though I figure these probably won't have analogues for $\mathsf{Prof}$.

Comment: @crystallinecohomology: you won't learn anything from classifying structures on a two-element set.  Find a real mathematical problem to study, such as the one in your user name! (PS I can't help with either of those topics.)

Comment: I understand it probably won't lead to anything really that interesting, it's just that I'm curious about whether there are other possible ways to put an associative and unital composition in $\mathsf{Rel}$ (and then study it a bit as a 2-category) following this end/coend strategy, besides the usual composition of relations and the "apartness composition".